# Batch put with pre-defined keys on Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, bigtable, low-level-api

I would like to do a batch put of entities with pre-defined keys using the low-level api for Java.

You can do a batch get:

```
 Map<Key,Entity> get(.Iterable<Key> keys)
```

However the batch puts all seem to want to allocate their own keys:

```
List<Key> put(Iterable<Entity> entities)
```

Documentation page: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService.html#put(java.lang.Iterable)

I'm trying to batch get on a collection of entities, update them, and then batch put them back into the datastore.  It makes sense that I should be able to do this without changing the values of their keys, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I brain farted by posting this question, but maybe this will help someone else in the future.  All you have to do is set the keys when you allocate the entities:

```
Entity entity = new Entity(key);
```

Or if you had previously pulled the entities from the datastore, the keys should already be set.